# select date from DateTimePicker - VBA

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, vba

I have a problem with selection date using `DateTimePicker`.

I would like to have a range of days which I set using two DTPs - from YY-MM-DD to YY-MM-DD. My code is like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Date LIKE '" + DateTimePicker1.Value + "' OR Date LIKE '" + DateTimePicker2.Value + "')"
```

...but it gives me only dates from DTP1 and from DTP2, of course. I'm working on Access database (.mdb) and Visual Basic 2010.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Try `WHERE ([Date] BETWEEN #" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "# AND #" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "#)"`

Comment: I belive the concatenation sign is actually `&` an ampersand and not a `+` plus for strings in vba

Comment: @mehow I think you can actually use both in VBA.

Comment: @Kapol yes but strictly for strings. if you do a `dim str$: str = "12" + "12" + 12` you get a type mismatch.

Comment: From Access 2007 onward there is a built in Date Selector for any text control bound to a field of type `Date`. If the control is unbound you can get it to show the Date Selector by setting the `Format` property to a date format such as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: @Alex K.  your code works perfectly! Great!

Comment: @Kapol If you get into the habit of always using & instead of + you avoid a lot of potential problems like "2"+2 == 4

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN #" + Format(DateTimePicker1.Value,"mm/dd/yyyy") + "# AND #" +  Format(DateTimePicker2.Value,"mm/dd/yyyy") + "#"
```